# Forms not submitting Input type="file" values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am submitting a simple form to an asp.net page. Everything works fine except the form does not submit the file input values.

```
<form id="mainform" action="http://<%=Request.Url.Authority %>/ABC/Handler/Submit.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' id='file_d6'data-mandatory='0' name='file_d6' style='visibility: hidden; position: absolute;'  onchange='showPreview(this)' />
<input type='file' id='file_d7'data-mandatory='0' name='file_d7' style='visibility: hidden; position: absolute;'  onchange='showPreview(this)' />

<input style='height: 100%;' type='submit' class='subCtrl'  onclick='return isReadyToSubmit();' >
</form>
```

In the function isReadyToSubmit I check the value of all input fields in the form. It shows me values of both file input fiels, but when I submit the form it submits all fields except file input

```
function isReadyToSubmit()
{
     $("form#mainform :input").each(function(){
         alert($(this).val());
     });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you should specify the input there are 2 types of input.

Comment: Are you getting other values then `type="file"`?

Comment: Why is the input file tag hidden ?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: yes there are text inputs and checkboxes i am getting their values in alert box and in aspx page too..

Comment: @guradio: can you please explain..

Comment: So you should either post you answer and accept it, or just delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not at client side but was at server side. I was using `Request.Form.GetKey(intIndex`) it gave me all other input values except files, but using `Request.Files[intIndex]` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The file post  is not present in the $_POST but in the $_FILES array.
Please try print_r($_FILES); at the top of your PHP script? Hope that this helps

Comment: i am posting this from to an aspx page.

Comment: and getting values using Request.Form.GetKey(index)

Comment: solved it, I was getting Files using wrong method, using Request.Files[index] solved my issue.